# Deleting old dynamically allocated memory in assignment operator overloading method in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, quadtree

I have two questions which are connected to each other.

I am implemeting a region quad-tree structure. In this QTree class, I have some fields and more importantly a

```
vector<QTree*> quads;
```

field that holds four divided regions of current square.
Firstly, I want to implement a destructor for this class. Note that I cannot define anything in public field in the class (If I were, this was a piece of cake!) so I did this:

```
QTree::~QTree ()
{
  if ( quads [ 0 ] != NULL )
  {
     for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
     {
        delete ( quads [ i ] );
     }
  } 
}
```

According to valgrind, this works ie. no memory leak and error but I am not very sure if it is. Could you state your opinion about destructor's validity?

Second issue is that, in the implementation of overloaded assignment operator of this class if I write after self-assignment check and before anything else in this method this:

```
delete this;
```

I take

*** Error in ` ': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007fffcb4d46d0 ***
: line 3: 4227 Aborted (core dumped)  leakcheck

error.

If I write (same code in destructor.)

```
if ( quads [ 0 ] != NULL )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        {
            delete ( quads [ i ] );
        }
    }
```

instead "delete this;" in overloaded assigment operator, I get no error.
What is wrong, could you clarify me?

EDIT:
I removed copy constructor.

Maybe the problem is using self destruction of an object. Here are some useful information on this: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this

Comment: What are `class QTree`'s data members?

Comment: `if ( quads [ 0 ] != NULL)` big red flag there.

Comment: @timrau except quads, all of them are stack variables. I think, this is what you are questioning.

Comment: Checkout [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: @mualloc  `in the implementation of overloaded assignment operator of this class`  If you implemented copy/swap, then you have none of these issues you mentioned in your assignment operator (provided that you have a working copy constructor and destructor).

Comment: @self I did not understand what you mean but let me mention about an important issue. quads vector is initialized to hold 4 NULL pointers in the constructor. When a square is divided, the pointers in this vector  are dynamically allocated to hold new QTree's square's values.

Comment: @mualloc Please post your assignment operator.  As a matter of fact, post your user-defined copy constructor also (you *did* write one, right?)

Comment: @mualloc To properly answer your question, there needs to be verification that your assignment operator and copy constructor are working correctly.  Assuming your copy constructor is working correctly, your assignment operator need not do all of this memory manipulation that is getting you in trouble (just by using copy / swap).  If you can't post anything else, then it becomes much harder, if not impossible, to tell you what's wrong.  At the very least, post the data members of your class (as was stated already).  If not, then you have to debug the code yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `delete` in C++ specifically allows 0/nullptr as an argument, so your test is superficial
2. Safer to write deallocation loop up to actual vector size `for ( int i = 0; i != quads.size(); i++ )`
3. `What is wrong, could you clarify me?`. When you call `delete this` you not only call to destructor (with quads deallocation), you then dellocate memory of your class, literally taking it out. If class is allocated on the stack, you'll get even more problems. Solution - refactor deallocation and call it from anywhere

   ```
   private void QTree::deallocate() {
     for(int i = 0; i != quads.size(); ++i) {
        delete (quads[i]);
     }
   }

   QTree::~Qtree() {
       deallocate();
       ...
   }

   QTree& QTree::operator=(const QTree& rhs) {
       deallocate();
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: 1) I did not understand what you mean.                                                        2) You are right but I am sure this was not the problem.                               3) The link I provided in the above thread also says self-destruct must be avoided when using stack objects but for the code you supplied I already mentioned  that I cannot declare anything in public fields so you cannot access quads in your deallocate method.

Comment: @mualloc having quads[0] equal to NULL is ok to call delete(quads[0]). op delete() has internal check for NULL, this is required by c++ standard

Comment: Now, I understand what you mean in the first one.

Comment: @mualloc sorry, missed qualifier for deallocate, edited, thank you for noticing. Concerning `delete this` it is wrong to call even is it was allocated on the heap. You literally yank memory from underneath the object. There is no place left to put data copied from `rhs`

Comment: Is the code correct I iteratively delete quads[i] in overloaded assignment operator method above? Note that the same code is also in destructor.

Comment: @mualloc Yes, I believe you're correct, same deallocation ought to be used in destructor and assingment op. This is why I think it is better to have it refactored into separate routine and call whenever you have to clear old resource either on destcruction of on copy from new resource

Answer (score 4):

In modern C++, unless you are in very specific cases, you should manage owning pointers using **smart pointer** classes, like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Note that STL smart pointers can be nicely combined with STL containers, making it possible to implement a kind of *"deterministic (reference-count-based) garbage collector"*.

In your case, I'd consider using:

```
// Supports copy semantics
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<QTree>> quads;
```

or:

```
// This is movable but not copyable
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<QTree>> quads;
```

depending on your needs and on your design.

In this way, you can enjoy the so called [*"Rule of Zero"*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three): the C++ compiler will *automatically* implement copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment, move assignment and destructor for you.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly, what you are trying to do is:

```
QTree& operator =(const QTree& rhs) {
    // destroy current content
    delete this;
    // clone and copy content of rhs to current quads
    if (rhs.quads[0] != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            quads[i] = new QTree(*rhs.quads[i]);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

So that you can avoid duplicating the code in the destructor

First thing: why `delete this` is not working as you expect: that is because after calling the object destructor (which is want you want to do), `delete this` will also free the memory of the object. Your own current object, the one you are going to use to assign copied values from the other object. Calling the destructor without freeing the memory is possible using `this->~Qtree()`

In fact, it is also possible to call a constructor without allocating memory using the placement new operator, so if you already have a copy constructor, you assignment operator could be:

```
QTree& operator=(const QTree& rhs) {
    this->~QTree();
    new(this)(rhs);
    return *this;
}
```

Looks neat, but unfortunately, it is not recommended to do this as it is not exception safe: if the constructor throws an exception, your object is going to be in a bad state.

One of the recommended way to implement the assignment operator is to use a nothrow "swap" method or function:

```
QTree& operator=(const QTree& rhs) {
    QTree tmp(rhs);
    swap(tmp)
    return *this;
}
```

Now that I answered the question, there are a few other issues with your code, especially it seems quite unnecessary to use a variable length vector to always store 4 items and always 4 items. Why no simply a QTree[4] array?